Clickhouse time comparison query optimization
I have an events table in CH with a dimension dim1 and a time column with PARTITION BY toStartOfDay(time) and ORDER BY (time, dim1). There are around 4B rows in the time range 2024-11-10 00:00:00 and 2024-11-11 23:00:00. I am running this query to compare some counts across two days for dim1 -
SELECT
    COALESCE(base.dim1, dim1.deal_type_name) AS dim1,
    base.dim1 AS dim1,
    comparison.dim1 AS dim1_prev,
    base.dim1 - comparison.dim1 AS dim1_delta
FROM (
        SELECT
            dim1 AS dim1,
            COUNT(request) AS dim1
        FROM events
        WHERE (time >= toDateTime('2024-11-11 00:00:00')) AND (time < toDateTime('2024-11-11 23:00:00'))
        GROUP BY 1
    ) base
Full OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        dim1 AS dim1,
        COUNT(request) AS dim1
    FROM events
    WHERE (time >= toDateTime('2024-11-10 00:00:00')) AND (time < toDateTime('2024-11-11 00:00:00'))
    GROUP BY 1
) AS comparison ON isNotDistinctFrom(base.dim1, comparison.dim1)
ORDER BY dim1 DESC
LIMIT 8

This runs fine and scans almost all the rows, to optimize further I changed the query to the below query so that inner comparison query only considers dim1 values which are present in base query thinking it will filter aggressively.
WITH base AS
    (
        SELECT
            dim1 AS dim1,
            COUNT(request) AS req_count
        FROM events
        WHERE (time >= toDateTime('2024-11-11 00:00:00')) AND (time < toDateTime('2024-11-11 23:00:00'))
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY req_count DESC
        LIMIT 8
    )
SELECT
    COALESCE(base.dim1, comparison.dim1) AS dim1,
    base.req_count AS req_count,
    comparison.req_count AS req_count_prev,
    base.req_count - comparison.req_count AS req_count_delta,
FROM base
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        dim1 AS dim1,
        COUNT(request) AS dim1
    FROM events
    WHERE (dim1 IS NULL) OR (dim1 IN (
        SELECT base.dim1
        FROM base
    )) and (time >= toDateTime('2024-11-10 00:00:00')) AND (time < toDateTime('2024-11-11 00:00:00'))
    GROUP BY 1
) AS comparison ON isNotDistinctFrom(base.dim1, comparison.dim1)
ORDER BY req_count DESC
LIMIT 8

But to my surprise it is slower than previous one and scans almost 1.5 times the actual rows present in underlying table.
Any thoughts whats happening here, is there way to further otpimize or full outer join query is the only way to go? Thanks

you trying compare LEFT JOIN and FULL OUTER JOIN
and for LEFT JOIN you also have (dim1 IS NULL) OR (dim1 IN (
which scan base twice
WITH base AS ( ...) it just substitution to original query without cache results

Yeah I thought CH would optimize the base CTE to run only once, anyways
